# Crash when adding a button to a panel view

Tags: android, panel

I have the following code that shows a panel.  It displays a button on the panel but as soon as I assign a Click Handler to it the app crashes!

It crashes on the line .setOnClickListener

```
Button button =  (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonclick);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                  hide();

                }
              });
```

LogCat shows...
09-22 14:54:09.953: ERROR/Error(7786): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-22 14:54:09.953: ERROR/Error(7786):     at com.pinkfroot.leefinder.leeFinderMain$PopupPanel.(leeFinderMain.java:598)

Adding a breakpoint further down shows that R.id.buttonclick has an id but button is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your error it sounds as if the Button returned by findViewById is coming back as a null reference. In which case your problem will be somewhere within findViewById (or the parameter passed to it).

Comment: Yes I can see that however there are many other things (not buttons) using findViewById that work fine.

Answer (score 0):

At which point do you have `setContentView(R.layout.main);`.
This code has to be invoked before you can access your button via `Button button =  (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonclick);`

Comment: I have that in my onCreate method and then the button code is in a different class within that called "PopupPanel"